# Q: E: Error reading the CPU table in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-17.04

I can not update or upgrade my computer by terminal.
Show the error message **E: Error reading the CPU table**.
how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 7):

In My case I have faced with corrupted dpkg installation and at the end it ended up with “E: Error reading the CPU table” even I enter  sudo apt-get update

Step to fix it.

> 1) Create tempory location for dpkg and download  relavent .deb file

```
 sudo mkdir /tmp/dpkg then

 cd tmp/dpkg
```

2) Downlod .deb file with relavent .deb file in http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/

```
sudo wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.19.0.5ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb
```

3) Manually go to that downloaded directory and extract the .deb file(GDebi installation might not work as well)

> Navigate to `<Your_Extracted_Folder>/usr/share/dpkg` and now you can
>   see the  set of files with  cputable file. We need to copy these files
>   to `/usr/share/dpkg`

4) Check `/usr/share/` having dpkg folder if not create it with

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/dpkg
```

5) `cd <Your_Extracted_Folder>/usr/share/dpkg`

6) `sudo cp * /usr/share/dpkg`
Now you can see all the files and it will fix the `“E: Error reading the CPU table”`

Answer (score 6):

In my case some file system corruption caused files in the directory `/usr/share/dpkg/` and the file `/usr/share/dpkg/cputable` wasn't found

to be deleted, concurrent access during some other operation?

- rsync / copying ( in my case rsync'ing ) from a known good installation appears to have fixed this particular problem
- possible alternative boot from a livecd and mount the target disk and copy

The command `strace apt update` showed the location of the missing file

Comment: I have copied the cputable file from other server and pasted in /usr/share/dpkg/. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have (unintentionally) "overwritten" your /usr/share directory with a file..

ls -l /usr/

-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1254 Feb  4 19:08 share*

drwxr-xr-x 193 root root  4096 Dec 10 09:09 share~/

I solved it by moving the file share* to share_bak and then renaming the directory share~ (to share). Problem solved!